# Update Python via Powershell

Tags: python, windows, update, powershell

We currently have older Windows QGIS installations on our clients that utilize Python 3.9.5.0. Due to identified vulnerabilities in this version, we are seeking to upgrade to the latest supported version (3.9.18 for QGIS).

Is there a Powershell command available to facilitate the update of Python distributed via QGIS?

Comment: When it comes to bundled Python deployments, they should always be updated by the program they are bundled with because upgrading the Python version yourself could cause things to break.  Are you trying to upgrade only the bundled Python deployment, which you shouldn't try, or are you trying to upgrade the entire application?

Comment: I'm interested in updating Python via QGIS Package Manager.
If there is a painless method to update the entire application, I'm also interested :)